# Why does `OP_CHECKSIGADD` allow TAPROOT keyspends?

Tags: script, multi-signature, taproot, opcodes

My understanding is this sig version is only for taproot keyspends, why is it allowed to be used in `OP_CHECKSIGADD`?

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e826b22da252e0599c61d21c98ff89f366b3120f/src/script/interpreter.h#L191

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/8035b5c80df51130af7cd398da84186ee42dd6e3/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not; that option is unreachable.

In `SigVersion::TAPROOT` mode, there is no script to speak of, so the script interpreter is never invoked with it. See line 417 where this is asserted.

The line you link to only makes sure that calling `OP_CHECKSIGADD` causes failures in the two other `SigVersion` modes that *are* reachable.